# how to get profile picture from facebook login api using codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

```
$user = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,link,picture');
<?php 
 $i=0;
 if($i<1)
 {
 foreach ($user as $key => $value):
 echo $key; 
 ?> : 

  <?php
 $image_url= $value; 
 echo $image_url;
  ?> 
 <img class="fb_profile" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $image_url; ?>/picture">
 <?php   
 endforeach;
 }
 ?>
```

I have used https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter for using facebook login sdk using codeigniter. I have got the values from it. BUt in case of fetching user profile picture, i print repeated image tag with info of a given user. i havent been able to find other way without error and and only get one image. Other than picture i get the values just fine

Comment: Can you post the contents of the $user array?

Comment: @MiguelSuarez i have edited the question with the contents of $user array

Comment: I don't see the contents of the $user array in the question. Can you copy - paste them into the question? use var_dump($user) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user's profile image, use the provided Facebook Id, I haven't used the picture field, but this should work:

```
<img class="fb_profile" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user['id']; ?>/picture">
```